# Cant install ruby-switch for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install ruby on rails on Ubuntu via bright box. I've installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev
```

But when I try to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-switch
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ruby-switch is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ruby-switch' has no installation candidate
```

What is the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: What did ruby-switch provide for you in a Rails context?

Comment: It manages the versions of ruby in the brightbox way

Comment: rvm-switch is (or was) primarily a developer tool, so this seems on topic.

Comment: I concur with @WayneConrad. SO permits questions regarding: "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, *or software tools commonly used by programmers*; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like ruby-switch is available anymore.  That's what apt-get is informing you of.

If you're looking for a way to manage the versions of Ruby, then there is [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/) available instead.  These two approaches are more standard and widely accepted as good ways to switch between Ruby version - but pick **only one**.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I was just thinking it would be easier to install via the brightbox (It is the treehouse way). Thanks a lot for the answer.